# How can I calculate number of days between two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, jupyter-notebook

If I have two dates (ex. 19960104 and 19960314), what is the best way to get the number of days between these two dates?
Actually I have to calculate many dates in my dataframe. I use the code:

```
`for j in range(datenumbers[i]):
    date_format = "%Y%m%d"
    a = datetime.strptime(str(df_first_day.date[j]), date_format)
    b = datetime.strptime(str(df_first_day.exdate[j]), date_format)
    delta = (b - a).days
    df_first_day.days_to_expire[j] = delta`
```

I need to put every difference between two dates in one of column of my dataframe. I wonder if there is a better way to do as not using for loop

Answer (score 0):

You will find dates much easier to handle if you first convert text to datetime.
Then it becomes trivial to compute a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) that answers your question.

```
import datetime as dt

fmt = '%Y%m%d'
d1 = dt.datetime.strptime('19960104', fmt)
d2 = dt.datetime.strptime('19960314', fmt)
print((d2 - d1).days)
```

This displays:

```
70
```

EDIT

If you choose to define a function:

```
def num_to_timestamp(ymd):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(str(num), '%Y%m%d')
```

then you can conveniently apply it to a column:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(num_to_timestamp)
```

Similarly the [`axis=1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) option lets you construct a column that is difference of two existing columns.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22615076)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I have to calculate many dates in my dataframe. I use the code:                                                                                                           for j in range(datenumbers[i]):
        date_format = "%Y%m%d"
        a = datetime.strptime(str(df_first_day.date[j]), date_format)
        b = datetime.strptime(str(df_first_day.exdate[j]), date_format)
        delta = (b - a).days
        df_first_day.days_to_expire[j] = delta

Comment: I need to put every difference between two dates in one of column of my dataframe. I wonder if there is a better way to do as not using for loop.